# Issues trying to get Gitlab DAST to login via Keycloak

Tags: gitlab

I have a website. When I first enter the website, I am redirected to a keycloak login page. After I input a username and password, I am redirected back. I want to use gitlab DAST to test my website.

According to the gitlab docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/dast/authentication.html), I need to put in the following values:

```
dast:
  variables:
    DAST_WEBSITE: "https://example.com"
    DAST_AUTH_URL: "https://example.com/login"
    DAST_USERNAME_FIELD: "css:[name=username]"
    DAST_PASSWORD_FIELD: "css:[name=password]"
    DAST_SUBMIT_FIELD: "css:button[type=submit]"
```

This is fine and all... except the DAST_AUTH_URL isn't fixed! When I click on my website, the redirected URL looks a bit like this:

```
https://{mywebsite.com}/auth/realms/gene/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce={nonce}
```

Some of these values will change each time, and will fail if accessed by a separate browser.

But if I put the DAST_AUTH_URL = DAST_WEBSITE (after all, when a user visits the website, they are immediately redirected), the logs show that the gitlab runner was never redirected. Instead, I keep getting error 403 (website replaced with {URL}).

```
2023-10-10 02:16:47,677 Requesting access to {URL}...
2023-10-10 02:16:48,584 HTTPError: 403
2023-10-10 02:16:51,588 Requesting access to {URL}...
2023-10-10 02:16:52,500 HTTPError: 403
2023-10-10 02:16:55,503 Requesting access to {URL}...
2023-10-10 02:16:56,411 HTTPError: 403
2023-10-10 02:16:59,411 Requesting access to {URL}...
2023-10-10 02:17:00,319 HTTPError: 403
2023-10-10 02:17:00,319 TargetNotAccessibleError: Last attempted access of target caused error: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url
```

What should I do to get the gitlab DAST to login?